# Delete record where duplicate in part of raw

Tags: sql, sql-server, delete-row

I need to delete all records in a table where the time between it 1 or 2 minute or the same and must be the same `ID` but keep the first record

```
ID             Time             SN  SD   WE FW
10  2014-06-30 19:17:37.000 I   0   100 0
10  2014-06-30 19:17:42.000 I   0   100 0
10  2014-06-30 19:17:46.000 I   0   100 0
10  2014-06-30 19:17:58.000 I   0   100 0
10  2014-06-30 20:37:46.000 I   0   100 0
```

or

```
ID             Time             SN  SD   WE FW
10  2014-07-01 21:10:33.000 I   0   100 0
10  2014-07-01 21:11:06.000 O   0   100 0
10  2014-07-02 20:53:36.000 I   0   100 0
10  2014-07-02 20:53:38.000 I   0   100 0
10  2014-07-02 20:54:33.000 O   0   100 0
10  2014-07-02 20:54:41.000 O   0   100 0
10  2014-07-02 20:55:22.000 o   0   100 0
```

to be

```
ID             Time             SN  SD   WE FW
10  2014-06-30 19:17:37.000 I   0   100 0
10  2014-06-30 20:37:46.000 I   0   100 0
```

and

```
ID             Time             SN  SD   WE FW
10  2014-07-01 21:10:33.000 I   0   100 0
10  2014-07-02 20:53:36.000 I   0   100 0
```

---

**ITS NOT Working**
sorry i am new @sql This MY Table content

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
      [USERID]
      ,[CHECKTIME]
      ,[CHECKTYPE]
      ,[VERIFYCODE]
      ,[SENSORID]
      ,[WorkCode]
      ,[sn]
FROM 
   [NEWFP].[dbo].[CHECKINOUT]
```

and I need to delete record that the time 2 or 1 minute and keep the first but the same user id.

I can't do it ?

Comment: Plz explain ur problem clearly!!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

```
DECLARE @Seconds INT = 120
DECLARE @Logs TABLE (
    ID INT,
    [Time] DATETIME
)
INSERT @Logs VALUES
(10, '2014-06-30 19:17:37.000'),
(10, '2014-06-30 19:17:42.000'),
(10, '2014-06-30 19:17:46.000'),
(10, '2014-06-30 19:17:58.000'),
(10, '2014-06-30 20:37:46.000'),
(10, '2014-07-01 21:10:33.000'),
(10, '2014-07-01 21:11:06.000'),
(10, '2014-07-02 20:53:36.000'),
(10, '2014-07-02 20:53:38.000'),
(10, '2014-07-02 20:54:33.000'),
(10, '2014-07-02 20:54:41.000'),
(10, '2014-07-02 20:55:22.000')

;WITH Logs AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        [Time],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Time]) AS RowNum
    FROM @Logs L
)
    --SELECT *, DATEDIFF(SS, L1.[Time], L2.[Time])
    DELETE L2
    FROM Logs L1
        INNER JOIN Logs L2
            ON L1.ID = L2.ID
                AND L1.RowNum = L2.RowNum - 1
    WHERE DATEDIFF(SS, L1.[Time], L2.[Time]) < @Seconds
SELECT * FROM @Logs
```

Comment: first thanks for your replay :) and i need this statement with all table not jest for this                                   (10, '2014-06-30 19:17:37.000'),
(10, '2014-06-30 19:17:42.000'),
(10, '2014-06-30 19:17:46.000'),
(10, '2014-06-30 19:17:58.000'),
(10, '2014-06-30 20:37:46.000'),
(10, '2014-07-01 21:10:33.000'),
(10, '2014-07-01 21:11:06.000'),
(10, '2014-07-02 20:53:36.000'),
(10, '2014-07-02 20:53:38.000'),
(10, '2014-07-02 20:54:33.000'),
(10, '2014-07-02 20:54:41.000'),
(10, '2014-07-02 20:55:22.000')

Comment: I had just setup the table variable for demonstration, but you can adapt it to your own tables by changing "@Logs" in the CTE expression to the name of your table. The process should work on any existing table, and I threw in a parameter so you could define how many seconds you are comfortable to group records.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific table, please try the code below. It assumes USERID is the "ID" from your original question and CHECKTIME is the "Time". Hope this works for you!

```
DECLARE @Seconds INT = 120
;WITH Logs AS (
    SELECT
        [USERID] AS ID,
        [CHECKTIME] AS [Time],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Time]) AS RowNum
    FROM [NEWFP].[dbo].[CHECKINOUT] L
)
    DELETE L2
    FROM Logs L1
        INNER JOIN Logs L2
            ON L1.ID = L2.ID
                AND L1.RowNum = L2.RowNum - 1
    WHERE DATEDIFF(SS, L1.[Time], L2.[Time]) < @Seconds
```