# Delete record where duplicate in part of raw 2 advanced

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I am new @ sql , table name CHECKINOUT DB Name NEWFP  i need to delete all record where the checktime between it  from 1 to 5  minute or the same and must be the same user id but keep the fires record

i ask the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445452/delete-record-where-duplicate-in-part-of-raw) but i cant understand answer

```
USERID      CHECKTIME          CHECKTYPE   VERIFYCODE   [SENSORID]    WorkCode   SN
10      2014-06-30 19:17:37.000    I           0            100            0      0
10      2014-06-30 19:18:42.000    I           0            100            0      0
10      2014-06-30 19:19:46.000    I           0            100            0      0
10      2014-06-30 20:17:58.000    I           0            100            0      0
10      2014-06-30 20:20:46.000    I           0            100            0      0
```

to be

```
USERID      CHECKTIME          CHECKTYPE   VERIFYCODE   [SENSORID]    WorkCode   SN
10      2014-06-30 19:17:37.000    I           0            100            0      0
10      2014-06-30 20:17:58.000    I           0            100            0      0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this

```
delete cio1 
from CHECKINOUT cio1
where exists (select 1 from CHECKINOUT cio2 
              where cio1.UserId = cio2.UserId
              and cio2.checktime < cio1.checktime
              and datediff(mi,cio2.checktime,cio1.checktime) between 0 and 5
             )

select * from CHECKINOUT
```

check on sql fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8da28/24

Comment: what about sql fiddle ?

Comment: I have illustrated the query in sql fiddle with sample data to understand it in better way.

Comment: This query can be simplified; see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8da28/24

Comment: +1 very well @Rimas. thanks. Shall I update my answer?